# Postgresql-11 : using pg_dump to dump both object definition and data for a select schema

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, postgresql-11

I know that it is possible to dump data and then schema separately,

But I am looking to dump both object definitions such as table, index,functions,views .. etc **for a select schema along with the data** for that schema's tables.

So far, I have tried the below command, using pg_dump.exe in windows cmd, and was able to bypass the password check which was a big Hassel for me.

```
SET PGPASSWORD=(password)
"C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin4\v4\runtime\pg_dump.exe" -h (hostname) -p 5432 -U (user name) -n (schema name) -d (database name)
```

**Where,**

- -h is hostname
- -p is port number
- -U is user name
- -n is schema name
- -d is database name

Overall, I am just trying to automate the process of dumping for backups, but I am unable to do so, since data is missing.

Comment: What exactly is your question. The command you have shown seems to do exactly what you want

Comment: I need the data of the tables as well. I am not getting the data of the tables, how would you get it ? I get only the schema objects

Comment: The command you show will dump the data.  Perhaps you are connecting to the wrong database/schema, in which you have a schema structure but with no data.

Comment: That command will include the data of the tables (unless they are in a different schema, obviously)

Comment: I tried using the same code.

Comment: It is dumping only schema table structures. Is it due to versioning issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inorder to get dump of both schemas along with data's present in schemas,

We can use the below command.

**Syntax:**

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin4\v4\runtime\pg_dump.exe" -h (hostname) -p 5432 -U (user name) -n (schema name) -d (database name) -t (schema name).*

**Sample:**

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin4\v4\runtime\pg_dump.exe" -h 192.168.0.1 -p 5432 -U postgres -n Business_Schema -d BusinessDatabase -t Business_Schema.*

Answer (score 1):

A PostgreSQL schema does not represent the structure (table, indexes, views etc.).
A schema is a namespace that logically groups the above in order to make the more manageable.

The same database can have multiple schema.
If you haven't manually created a schema you only have the default one (`public`).

Try to run your `pg_dump` command without the `n` parameter and you should have all the data and structure in the resulting file.
If you're building a backup system consider using the [custom archive](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) format `-Fc` or use something like `gzip`.

Comment: Thanks Ionut, and yes my database has multiple schemas and data is present in only one select schema, all the others are just objects. I am in need of taking backup of a select schema alone with its table data's, is there any way for it

Comment: Since `-n` takes a pattern did you try `-n 'schema_name'` or even `-n '*schema_name*'`?

Comment: -n schema_name without * in them.

Comment: Can you post some of the commands you tried and the result you got?

Comment: I was able to figure out an answer thanks to you. Thanks a lot for your suggestions.

Comment: Added the answer below.